# Open the drop down list permanently of select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 for multiple value selection. I need to display the drop down list permanently.

Right now when we select or click the input box of select2, the drop down list is displayed. I'd like to know if there is any way we can always show the list.

Answer (score 32):

From the select2 documentation, [here](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation):

```
    $("#select").select2({
            closeOnSelect: false
    });
```

Comment: Thank You @Terence, though if i unfocus from the input box of select2 it would be hidden. I need to keep the drop down menu always open. I'm trying manually by checking the classes on opening and closing of select2 and would write some jquery on change function there.

Comment: closeOnselect works if your select is in multiselect mode..see the documentation

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var list = $("#select").select2({
    closeOnSelect: false
}).on("select2:closing", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}).on("select2:closed", function(e) {
    list.select2("open");
});
```

For Ref [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/alelase/j79g9u6z/)