# select2 open without focus

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I use jquery select2 in my project and need to open the select2 all the time.
(link for this plugin: https://select2.github.io/)
I tried `$('#select2id').select2("open")`, but this keeps focusing on this element. I cannot focus on other inputs in this page. Any other ideas?

---

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/vff6t9aa/

Comment: Can you please post some working example code or link ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open the drop down list permanently of select2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107963/open-the-drop-down-list-permanently-of-select2)

Comment: @mhu Acutually I don't use the multiple option.

Comment: See also select2 issue 1416:  https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1416

Comment: @sodawillow I added a jsfiddle example

Comment: @mhu It is the problem but the code there doesn't work.

Comment: This strikes me as a weird way to use this plugin.

Comment: @Mathletics You have the same problem?

Comment: No, I'm having a hard time understanding why you would have a selectbox permanently open. Are you using it as a kind of menu? It seems like it would be easier to just write code that does that then it would be to hack Select2.

Comment: @Mathletics Yes I use it as a menu, since it has search function. Do you know any menu plugin with search? That should help too. Thanks.